# How does the Cross section of a toy hovercraft affect on the time that it hovers?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure

My question is about a toy hovercraft - a balloon connected to a CD. I need to know about something. How does cross section of the pipe affect the time that the toy hovercraft hovers above the surface?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at any of the links in my earlier answers/ comments? They contain the equations you need. Find them, and see what you can learn from them. Then ask for more help when you are still stuck. By the way - nice diagram.

Comment: Which ones? can you show them to me please?

Comment: The comment with the link was http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170556/how-pressure-effects-on-the-time-that-a-toy-hovercraft-hovers/170560#comment360492_170560

Comment: And more at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html

Comment: Sir I studied the all but I didn't find the answer of my new question. The effect of cross section on the time. I mean for example what will happen if we cover half of the pipe ( cross section ).

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer to your question can be found at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ppois2.html#tub

There it shows that the flow rate goes as the **4th power** of the radius of a pipe - so if you double the diameter, air will flow 16x faster.

The reason behind this is something I described in some detail in [this earlier answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/168075/26969).

Comment: OK sir, but what about the time. You proved that air flows 16x faster but air goes through a smaller area. How about the time? What would the relation of the r ( of the pipe ) and the time that hovercraft hovers?

Comment: If the air flows 16x more slowly, it will take 16x longer for the same volume of air to escape, assuming that the air flow is still sufficient for hovering - which depends on how snug the fit is between your disk and the table.