# How is power of a water pump related to amount of water delivered from pipe?

Tags: work, power

My book says:

> Suppose a pump motor is used to deliver water at a certain rate from a
>   given pipe. To get n times the water from same pipe in same time the
>   power must be increased by $n^3$ times.

I cant understand why?Shouldn't the power be increased by n times as $power$=rate of $work $ done and work done is being increased by n times ?
Or am I having a conceptual mistake?

Answer (score 1):

For turbulent flow, the friction goes up as the square of the velocity. So the force (pressure) goes as $n^2$. And you are moving $n$ times more liquid. The velocity (or volume flow) increases by $n$.

The two factors combine to give the cube law since power = force times velocity, or pressure times flow rate.

Comment: I did'nt understand why friction goes up as the square of velocity.Is that a formula or something?

Comment: Yes it is. See if you can understand [this link](http://www.nzifst.org.nz/unitoperations/flfltheory5.htm) - although it states the $v^2$ relationship as a given. Also, [this earlier answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/168075/26969) talks a bit more about fluid flow profiles - but while it addresses a different aspect, there may be some insights there for you.